# ImportError: No module named geoip2.database

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, ssh

I'm installing modern honeypot network and currently stuck on geoip2.
I have installed geoip2 via pip using this command:

```
pip install geoip2
```

I also add geoip2 location (/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages) to pythonpath:

```
export PYTHONPATH="/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages:/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages"
```

I also changed the permission using this command:

```
sudo chmod -R ugo+rX /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
```

However when I'm trying to import geoip2.database it leave this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/hpfeeds/examples/geoloc/geoloc.py", line 9, in <module>
    import geoip2.database
ImportError: No module named geoip2.database
```

**Update:**

I found something. If I import geoip2 via SSH it works, but not if I import it locally (using file).

Comment: Try removing any compiled code file like `geoip2.pyc `.

Comment: @MayankPorwal I delete them but the problem still persist.

Comment: These kind of problems normally occur due to overlooking some tiny thing while setup. Can't really say much about it.

Comment: @MayankPorwal If I import geoip2 via SSH it works, but not if I import it locally (using file).

Comment: Ubuntu example : `sudo apt install python-geoip2` → Provides `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/geoip2/database.py`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are installing geoip2 with the desired user.